# Spivak. Calculus. Convergence of the improper integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Spivak 3rd edition. Chapter 19, exercise 36.

Show that the following improper integral converge.$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \,\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

Answer: Since $$\bigg|\int_M^N\frac{1}{x^2} \sin\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\bigg|\leqslant\int_M^N\frac{1}{x^2} \bigg|\sin\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\bigg|\,\mathrm dx \leqslant \int_M^N\frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx \leqslant \frac{1}{M}$$ for all $0\leqslant M \leqslant N$

**The value of the integral from** $\mathbf1$ **to** $\mathbf M$ **is within** $\mathbf 1/M$ **of all later values**, so the limit must exist.

***My question***. The line of the inequality is clear. Because $\int_M^N\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{N-M}{NM} \leqslant\frac{1}{M}$ Meanwhile $0\leqslant M \leqslant N$. But I couldn't deduce the judgement which I have marked it with bold letters.

Could anybody explain me please.

Comment: Your bolded sentence simply means that $|\int_1^N\dots-\int_1^M\dots|\le1/M$ for every $N\ge M,$ which is what has just been proved.

Comment: Oh thanks.  Since I tried to proof $\int_1^M-\int_M^N \leqslant 1/M$

Comment: This integral is funny. By substitution $x:=1/y$ we get $$\int\limits_1^\infty \sin(y+y^{-1})\,dy$$ This intergral is thus convergent although it is not obvious if we forget the relation with the original integral.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, apparently, you didn't apply the change of variables to the bounds of integral. Aside from that, the integral you wrote, does not converge.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Indeed it should be from $0$ to $1.$ Thanks. Then the absolute convergence is obvious.